# How to stop 3rd party domain to redirect to my website in sqaurespace ? is there any scripts for it?

Tags: javascript, squarespace

An external person from my client company registered a domain and redirected to my client URL.

For instance, if you type unwanteddomain.com it redirects to myclientdomain.com.

Is there any way to block or redirect (for second time) to nowhere the unwanteddomain.com ?

My website is in squarespace

Comment: This sounds like something you're paying for their service to offer support for. You could define a rewrite in the `.htaccess` if there is one, but personally I'm not familiar with squarespace. On another note hi, welcome to SO! This is more of a support question than coding related so don't get dissuaded if you possibly receive down votes, but best of luck finding your remedy!

Comment: Thank you @ChrisW.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, but you need to write in some backend code language such as PHP, Python, Ruby etc.

But if you dont have any experience with this, I would contact you server provider, and ask them to help you block the domains.

And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you @flubssen , Yes I have experience in PHP , could you help me with this

Comment: Here is a guide on how to block an IP address in PHP
https://perishablepress.com/how-to-block-ip-addresses-with-php/